# C++ Binary Search to find the index of fixed point

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am implementing a function that finds a fixed point where A[i] = i.

```
size_t find_fixed_point(const vector<int>& list)
{
    auto lower = list.begin();
    auto upper = list.end() - 1;

    while (lower < upper)
    {
        auto mid = lower + (upper-lower)/2;

        if ( *mid <= (mid - list.begin()) )
        {
            // keep searching on left side
            upper = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            // keep searching on right side
            lower = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return lower - list.begin();
}
```

so if I apply this to the following vector

```
    vector<int> numbers = {-10, -5, 1, 3, 13, 13, 50, 70};
```

and

```
auto temp = find_fixed_point(numbers);
cout << numbers[temp];
```

It is supposed to give 3 as fixed point but it does not work just giving me -10.

The algorithm looks okay but it does not work. Anybody has an idea? Thanks,

Comment: Iterators are useful when you don't need to track the index of the element, you only need to tasverse the container. In your case is more convenient to use a simple integer index, because you are comparing `V[i]==i`

Comment: I'd run in in a *debugger*.

Comment: Is this ok? `if ( *mid <= (mid - list.begin()) )`

Comment: Is numbers always ordered from smallest to largest?

Comment: @cpp the purpose it to find `A[i] == i`, so yes, that is intentional.

Comment: Your are not binary searching for an i that A[i] = i. by `*mid <= (mid - list.begin())`, you mean from math's perspective `A[i] <= i - A[0]` , which does not code what you mean.

Comment: Yeah it is binary search tree. Apply to sorted list.

Comment: @lulyon `*mid <= (mid - list.front())` evaluates to `A[i] <= i - A[0]`, `begin()` returns an iterator (or an index).

Comment: @ilent2 That explains everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have your comparison operator around the wrong way:

```
size_t find_fixed_point(const vector<int>& list)
{
    auto lower = list.begin();
    auto upper = list.end() - 1;

    while (lower < upper)
    {
        auto mid = lower + (upper-lower)/2;

        if ( *mid >= (mid - list.begin()) )
        {
            // keep searching on left side
            upper = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            // keep searching on right side
            lower = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return lower - list.begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

size_t find_fixed_point(const vector<int>& list)
{
    auto lower = list.begin();
    auto upper = list.end() - 1;

    while (lower < upper)
    {   
        auto mid = lower + (upper-lower)/2;

        if ( *mid > (mid - list.begin()) )
        {   
            // keep searching on left side
            upper = mid;
        }   
        else if ( *mid < (mid - list.begin()) )
        {   
            // keep searching on right side
            lower = mid + 1;
        }   
        else 
            return mid - list.begin();  
    }   
     return lower - list.begin();
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers = {-10, -5, 1, 3, 13, 13, 50, 70};  
    auto temp = find_fixed_point(numbers);
    cout << numbers[temp];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One posiible solution to this is to use standard library algorithms, in this case [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
int index = 0;
auto result = std::find_if( std::begin( v ) , std::end( v ) , [&]( int value ) { return value == index++; } );
```

But the problem here is that `std::find_if()` is *O(n)*, uses simple linear trasversal.

So if you want a *O(logn)* solution, as in your question, use your binary search solution.
I'm agree with ilent2 answer, the problem is the "swapped" comparison: Should be `>=`, no `<=`.